# URL Regex in Visual Studio Winforms C#

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I want to use a Regular Expression to validate the URL entered in my textbox `txtWeb`, however all Regular Expressions I've found doesn't work in Visual Studio 2013. The errors is caused by all the backslashes and dots. I don't know if there's a solution to make it working? Here's the Regex that I want to use :

```
/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/
```

And here's how I'm trying to use it :

```
if (txtWeb.Text != "")
            {
                Regex regex = new Regex("/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/");
                Match match = regex.Match(txtWeb.Text);
                if (!match.Success)
                {
                    MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Ce site web est invalide", "Message d'erreur", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    erreur = false;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the forward slashes exists at the start and end and also use verbatim string, so that you don't need to  escape all the backslashes..

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(https?://)?([\da-z.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([/\w .-]*)/?$");
```

This is a c# regex, not js or perl where the regex pattern could be included within forward slashes like,

```
/foo/
```

For the sake of performance, I just modified `([\/\w \.-]*)*`  to `([\/\w \.-]*)`

Comment: It  was for C# and with your answer, it's now working, thanks for the help Avinash